# How to change unit scale for all future meshes

Tags: scale, units

I am new to Blender. After import any mesh to Unreal the size is bigger twice. So I changed Unit Scale to 0,5
[image]

But whe I add a new mesh it is bigger twice.
[image]

Both has scale 1x1x1.

Am I missing something? Is there any option to change unit scale for all present and future meshes at project? Or for all projects?

Thaks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But when a NEW file is created the default returns! How to fix that? (I'm working all times with milimetric pieces).

The solution is here:
[Blender 2.8: units of scale, grid, and default size of objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153681/blender-2-8-units-of-scale-grid-and-default-size-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

When I added new mesh default size was 2m (but scale 1x1x1). It is in the menu (e.g. Add Cube)

[image]

Change it to 1m and size is same as scale