# How do I change the units to meters or create an object that is X mm wide?

Tags: 3d-printing, units

So I want to make a model for 3D-printing and searched for a guide on how to change the units to metric units first of course, but the guides I found were totally outdated, because there seems to have been massive changes to the UI.
I don't even know where to start in the Manual and got kinda lost in the pages there without finding an answer.

**What I want to do:**

**1) Change the "blender" units to metric units.**

**2) Display the volume of objects in Blender.**

Thank you guys so much in advance for any help!

Comment: PS: I am new to using the program, so please excuse me if my question is dumb. I read on a guide on how to do a 3D printing object in Blender from 2 years ago and the author said that you have to change the units from "Blender units" to "metric units" and describes a "properties" submenu, but I am unable to find the menu, because the UI has totally changed and the description of which icon has this function doesn't fit anymore.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please keep only one question per post, ask as many as you need. Also do a search before posting, these are very frequent questions and have already been answered before. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63113/is-it-possible-to-display-volume-of-a-mesh-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/blender-units-vs-metric/17974#17974 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153681/blender-2-8-units-of-scale-grid-and-default-size-of-objects

Answer (score 2):

Just to make it easier for other 2.8x users.

Change your units to metric.
*Properties panel > Scene Tab > Units*

[image]

To check the volume of objects, enable the *3D-Print Toolbox* addon.
*Preferences > Addons* and click the checkmark.

[image]

After it's enabled, you can see the volume here.
*Sidebar > 3D Print tab*

[image]

Comment: This answer is great, but I don't see that sidebar for the add-on on the right side...


It kinda looks like this to me:

https://ibb.co/gvwRbh5

... how did you add the pictures to the post?

Comment: Hey there :). *View > Sidebar*. Or just click the little arow on top . Or press **N**.

Comment: Also, you can now mark the answer as accepted **✓**. ;)

Comment: Man I hate it when they disappear before hitting the damn accept button. :P

Comment: @BLayer Yeah, it used to bug me too :D.

Comment: _Used_ to? Lucky devil. :)